# Linq expression to select rows when no other row in the table matches a condition

Tags: c#, sql, linq, where-clause

I have a table with 3 columns:

---

**Name**    varchar

**Test1**   bit

**Test2**   bit

**Group**   varchar

---

**Objective:**

I want to select all rows where only test1 is true per each name per group.

---

To clarify, take these example records:

```
Name | Test1 | Test2 | Group
Foo    True    False   Group 1
Bar    True    False   Group 1
Bar    False   True    Group 2
Foo    False   True    Group 1
123    True    False   Group 1
```

The 2nd row will be selected as it has never tested true for Test2 for that same group with the same 'Name' value.

The 1st row will not be selected as it has, at some point in the table, tested true for Test2 with the same group name.

The final row will be selected as it has never tested true for Test2.

NOTE: I have the group name to explicitly search by.

**What I've Tried**

What I've tried (and it works) is to select all of the rows where test 1 is true. I've then done another search (iterating through the results from this first query) for each id and tested if it appears again. What I've done here though is a workaround, I understand there's a lot of 'where not exists' capabilities of Linq and I want to utilise them to improve the state of what I've written so far so hopefully I can roll it all up into one statement.

**Code Example**

```
var items = itemsTable.Where(o => o.Group.Equals(GroupName) && o.Test1);
```

Comment: objective and forecast of result have contradictions

Comment: Just to understand the example, you say "The 2nd row will be selected as it has never tested true for Test2 for that same group." I see row 4 with test2 = true for the same group, maybe I misunderstood it?

Comment: Yes but the 'Name' is different. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var items = itemsTable.Where(o => !o.Test2 && 
    !itemsTable.Any(x => x.Name == o.Name && x.Group == o.Group && x.Test2));
```

Comment: Nice edit, and nice solution overall. Thanks a LOT for this mate. I've learnt a lot already just from reading this and using it.

Comment: I think you are querying itemsTable twice, aren't you? Like a nested sql select

Comment: Pretty much yes, I don't know of a more elegant way around it for now. This does the trick.

Comment: yes, it's like nested SQL select (but that's not the same as querying the table twice).
You also go twice over the data - first to group and then to filter (the Any call) - it's inevitable

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
var items = itemsTable.GroupBy(e => new { e.Name, e.Group }, e => e)
     .Where(g => !g.Any(e => e.Test2) &&  g.Key.Group.Equals(groupName))
     .SelectMany(e => e).ToList();
```